# Exibir cores em porcentagem

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer um aplicativo para tirar uma foto, exibir em imageview e extrair as cores com a biblioteca Palette. Tudo isso eu já fiz.
O que eu preciso é exibir o resultado (Population) em porcentagem do total e não em número de pixels. Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda?
Desde já agradeço.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if( convertView == null ) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from( getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.color_item, parent, false );
        holder.view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.view );
        convertView.setTag( holder );
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.view.setBackgroundColor(getItem(position).getRgb());
    holder.view.setTextColor(getItem(position).getBodyTextColor());
    holder.view.setText("Population: " + getItem(position).getPopulation());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para isso deve se saber o total de Pixels que a imagem tem!

Para isso faça da seguinte forma:

```
int totalPxls = 0;
for(Palette.Swatch swatch : palette.getSwatches())
{
    totalPxls += swatch.getPopulation();
}
```

Com este valor, podemos aplicar a regra de 3 para sabermos a porcentagem:

```
Double porcentagem = ((getItem(position).getPopulation()*100.0D)/totalPxls);
```

Para que você possa transportar o totalPxls da sua `Activity` para o `Adapter`:

```
public class SwatchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Integer totalPixels;
    public SwatchAdapter(Context context, int resource, Integer totalPixels) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.totalPixels = totalPixels;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thiago, obrigado pela atenção mas não consigo. Eu tenho 2 classes MainActivity onde já tenho aquele loop que você sugeriu, só acrescentei a contagem de Pixels, nas não consigo calcular a % porque não tenho aí a posição dos itens ainda e na classe SwatchAdapter, por ignorância minha, não consigo obter o totalPxls calculado na MainActivity.

Comment: Adicione no construtor do seu SwachtAdapter mais um parâmetro. O total de pixels. E na classe adicione mais uma propriedade. Assim pode se usar em seu método

Comment: Desculpe Thiago mas não sei "adicionar mais uma propriedade na classe"

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar!  Estamos aqui para lhe ajudar! Estou a caminho de casa. Quando chegar edito a resposta e lhe explico !

Comment: Editei! tente implementar, e qualquer dúvida, poste aqui!

Comment: Consegui Thiago. Mudei um pouco mas sua ajuda foi fundamental. Agora posso continuar meu projeto. Na verdade abandonei o loop porque estava acumulando o totalPxls. Vou tentar editar e postar minha classe SwatchAdapter porque pode ser útil para alguém.

Comment: Não sei editar......